# Pgrouting install debian 7.5 whezy

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, pgrouting

I need to install pgRouting on a Debian 7.5 64-bit server.

I have PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 1.5 running. But somehow I can not install pgRouting.

1 - To use add-apt-repository ran the command:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
```

2 - I entered the site georepublic `https://launchpad.net/ ~ / + archive / ubuntu / pgrouting-unstable` ppa to get the source to add to the list but only has to Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you PostGIS 2.0 or higher. In the documentation it says, that PostGIS 1.5 is necessary, and I guess it works. But I don't think many people are still using PostGIS 1.5

There are pgRouting packages for Debian for "sid". But it requires PostGIS 2.1: https://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-9.3-pgrouting

The pgRouting repository on Launchpad is for Ubuntu, not for Debian. And it requires PostGIS 2.0 or higher as well.

Comment: So I should upgrade my postgresql to version 9.3 and later postgis to version 2.1 and then install the debian packages available pgrouting. 
It seems the more correct path as yet unable to solve the problem. 
You have a how to on how to upgrade?

Comment: To upgrade pgRouting from version 1.x to version 2.x you only need to update your application. But if you need to update a database with PostGIS, then you best consult the PostGIS documentation.

Comment: link no longer works

Comment: @its30 , do you expect a 5 years old answer with software versions officially not supported anymore to be still valid?